# How to write a VBA/use a chain of commands that return number of cells that fall within a certain date and cell color?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, ms-office

I'm trying to make a scorecard that finds cells dates within a certain range (Ex:May1st- May31st) that contain a certain cell color (Ex: green) in a specified column. Ideally I want it to tell me how many cells contain these conditions and return a number.

These links were the closest thing I can find to what I need but I'm not sure how to implement searching for dates
https://www.exceltip.com/tips/how-to-get-color-of-the-cell-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel-2010.html

https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/count/how-to-count-colored-cells

This is an example of what my goal is:

```
Date         Cell Color
5/24/2019    green
2/4/2019     green
4/3/2019     red
5/15/2019    red
7/5/2018     green
5/1/2019    green

Result:    2
```

My goal is to have the code count May dates and if they are colored green. The actual spreadsheet won't say the cell color I'm just typing it for reference.

Comment: Are these cells green because of conditional formatting?

Comment: No, the colors are manually entered into the cells.

Comment: You can use `COUNTIFS()` to count the times a value falls within a certain date, or just `COUNTIF()` to see which cells have "red", or whatever...